# How to restrict parallel jobs to particular agents in Declarative Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have 3 nodes: A, B, C

On each of these nodes I set up a Jenkins agent with its own root directory
They all have the following label: test && database && mysql

I want to run a job in parallel on all 3 nodes, to clean the workspace folder on them
To achieve that, I wrote this Jenkins script

```
def labels = "test && mysql && database"

def getNodesName(labels){
    def targets = []
    def nodes = Jenkins.instance.getLabel(labels).getNodes()
    for(node in nodes){
        targets.add(node.getNodeName())
    }
    return targets
}

def nodes = getNodesName(labels)

def cleanWSTasks(targets){
    tasks = [:]
    for(target in targets){
        tasks[target] = {
            node(target){
                script {
                    cleanWs()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return tasks
}

pipeline{
    agent none
    
    stages{
        
        stage ('Clean Workspace'){
            steps{
                script{
                    parallel cleanWSTasks(nodes)
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

So I thought with node(target) in the cleanWsTasks function I already told Jenkins to restrict the execution of the task only on the particular target node I want. So that all 3 nodes will start cleaning their own workspaces at the same time.

However, what I see is that only 1 node picked up the task to cleanUp the workspace, and it does it 3 times.

For example, it shows:

Running on node A in ...

clean up workspace ..

Running on node A in ...

clean up workspace ..

Running on node A in ...

clean up workspace ..

What did I do wrong in my code? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node step is working correctly, the problem you're coming across has to do with how you're defining your tasks.
In your for loop, you're assigning this closure:

```
          {
            node(target){
                script {
                    cleanWs()
                }
            }
```

to `tasks[target]`.

The code inside the closure won't get evaluated until you execute the closure. So even though you assign `node(target)` inside the for loop, `target`'s value won't get evaluated until `parallel tasks` runs, which is when the closure is executed. That happens after the for loop has finished running and so `target`'s value is the name of the last node in your list of nodes.

An easy fix for this is to create a variable in your for loop that's equal to target and use that inside the closure, because you will force the evaluation of `target` to happen inside your for loop, instead of when the closure runs. 
That would look like this:

```
def cleanWSTasks(targets){
    tasks = [:]
    for(target in targets){
        def thisTarget = target
        tasks[thisTarget] = {
            node(thisTarget){
                script {
                    cleanWs()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return tasks
}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh I didn't know that this is how it would behave! Thank you so much it worked!